# Why isn't Chrome caching responses, even when cache-control header is present?

Tags: google-chrome, caching, cache-control

I am trying to understand WHEN Chrome caches things and how it decides what it caches.
For example, I visited this news article and opened the DevTools.
https://www.nextgov.com/ideas/2020/07/so-much-decentralized-internet/167281/

I've ensured that Cache is enabled (i.e. "Disable Cache" in unchecked).

When I refresh the page, the call for `167281/` gets made again. It is not retrieved from the cache. This is despite the fact that a `cache-control` header is set on the response.

Why is Chrome not caching this (and so many other resources) on the page?

[image: Chrome Cache]

[image: Cache DevTools]

Comment: I am having a similar issue, where PageSpeed Insights is showing me resources under the Audit "Serve static assets with an efficient cache policy", even though they have the cache-control tag set to one year.

Comment: @MiguelMateo maybe you are setting cache-control tag for the html page to one year, but not for the static assets (images, css files, .js libs)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you set `cache-control: max-age=...` you are saying to the requester that is safe to cache the resource for this long.

But its up to each browser (or applications in general) to decide when to actually cache. Mobile browsers may only cache small resources and desktop browsers may as well do the opposite.

Given [your example](https://www.nextgov.com/ideas/2020/07/so-much-decentralized-internet/167281/) in Firefox Developer Edition 80.0b5 after some reloads the page started to cache, changing the request cache-control to `if-modified-since`. This means the browser have the resource cached but will query the server for the resource just to check if it still up-to-date. If it is, the server (or some intermediary network router) will just return a 304 response with no actual content, which is exactly the case you showed:

[image]
[image]

But when I hit enter in the URL bar or when I use the navigation buttons, the cache is used without any actual request:

[image]

It's important to add that the cache-control is a hint to just not the actual requester: intermediaries will also use this informations to cache responses and make next requests load faster. And that even if the main resource (the html page) is cached, all assets linked in the page have their own `cache-control` tag.

The "transferred" column on dev-tools seems to show better if the resource was effectively cached locally or not:

[image]

Comment: So in my case, why is it making a new request if it's getting 304 ?

Comment: After the 304 result (with a empty body), you are making no new requests for this resource. But the same process happens to all resources linked (images, css, js libraries) or requested dynamically (pings, data collection) from the page.

Comment: Thanks! Can you make this more clear in your answer? I didn't understand that the call doesn't actually get content in the response

Answer (score 4):

The server returns HTTP status code 304 which means to tell browser that its cache is still valid, and it should use it.

Quote from https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Caching:
"When a validation request is made, the server can either ignore the validation request and response with a normal 200 OK, or it can return 304 Not Modified (with an empty body) to instruct the browser to use its cached copy. The latter response can also include headers that update the expiration time of the cached document"

Comment: So then why doesn't the browser heed this instruction and use the cached version ?

Comment: ...If you click on the refresh/reload button or press the F5 hotkey on your web browser, this will trigger a “soft refresh” on the web browser where it will check against the web server to see if the files are modified. If modified, the web browser will pull the latest version of the file and if not modified, the web browser will continue to use the cache version. A soft refresh takes very little bandwidth just to check the HTTP response headers of the files to determine if the files are modified.
Read More: https://www.raymond.cc/blog/refresh-webpage-with-soft-or-hard-reload-in-web-browsers/